# Strange code appearing on website footer after adding GTM code

Tags: google-tag-manager

We are having strange issue after implement GTM on our website. It usually after 2 days and not gets deleted that.

Only the header script is causing this issue, body code works fine.

Also, the code is working fine like its provide tracking but the strange code is appearing.

The strange code image is attached.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLQPK.png)

I need to find out the root cause and to remove this code from website.

Answer (score -1):

If you think this is caused by Google Tag Manger

### First step

It will be test to block the GTM request in Chrome devtool

[image]

If the weird text is gone. Then yes it should be caused by GTM

### Second step

Export the GTM as a JSON file.

[image]

You will get a JSON file and open it with code editor or notebook.

Try to search the keyword with the weird text. If you find it, you will know which Tag or Variable contains it and why it looks like broken.